# How to return an array from a recursive function

Tags: ruby

I have a board (multidimensional array). You start from the upper left corner and can move right or down. The base case is the lower right corner.

I made a function that looks for all possible moves and their values within the board. When the base case is reached, the moves and values are stored as an array `ARR_SUMNUM`.

```
ARR_SUMNUM = []
def arr_all_moves(ary,a=0,b=0,sum_num=0,directions="")
  rows = ary.length
  cols = ary[0].length
  goal = rows-1 + cols-1
  curr_num = ary[a][b]
  sum_num += curr_num
  if [a,b] == [rows-1,cols-1]
    ARR_SUMNUM.push([sum_num, directions])
    return
  end
  if a == rows -1 
    return arr_all_moves(ary,a,b+1,sum_num,directions+="right ")
  elsif b == cols -1
    return arr_all_moves(ary,a+1,b,sum_num,directions+="down ")
  end
  arr_all_moves(ary,a,b+1,sum_num,directions+="right ")
  directions.chomp!("right ") ##### I realize this was the source of all my issues
  arr_all_moves(ary,a+1,b,sum_num,directions+="down ")
  return ARR_SUMNUM
end

board = [   [1,3,4],
            [5,6,999],
            [8,9,10],
            [11,12,13],
            [2000,42,13]
        ]
p arr_all_moves(board)
```

How do I get this function to work without a constant like `ARR_SUMNUM` and use a local variable instead? I tried to use `arr_sumnum` instead, but I get an empty array.

Comment: You should use `"down "` instead of `"left "` as thats what the problem requires

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way might just be to pass the array down the line with each call by setting it as one of the method arguments.

```
def arr_all_moves(ary, a=0, b=0, sum_num=0, directions=" ", arr_sum_num=[])
  rows = ary.length
  cols = ary[0].length
  goal = rows-1 + cols-1
  curr_num = ary[a][b]
  sum_num += curr_num
  if [a,b] == [rows-1,cols-1]
    arr_sum_num.push([sum_num, directions])
    return
  end
  if a == rows -1
    return arr_all_moves(ary,a,b+1,sum_num,directions+="right ", arr_sum_num)
  elsif b == cols -1
    return arr_all_moves(ary,a+1,b,sum_num,directions+="left ", arr_sum_num)
  end
  arr_all_moves(ary,a,b+1,sum_num,directions+="right ", arr_sum_num)
  arr_all_moves(ary,a+1,b,sum_num,directions+="left ", arr_sum_num)
  return arr_sum_num
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways, one was already mentioned that involved propagating the array down to the recursive function calls. Another would be to actually propagate the array upward and add them in the calling function.

```rb
def arr_all_moves(ary,a=0,b=0,sum_num=0,directions=" ")
  rows = ary.length
  cols = ary[0].length
  goal = rows-1 + cols-1
  curr_num = ary[a][b]
  sum_num += curr_num
  if [a,b] == [rows-1,cols-1]
    return [[sum_num, directions]]
  end
  if a == rows -1 
    return arr_all_moves(ary,a,b+1,sum_num,directions+="right ")
  elsif b == cols -1
    return arr_all_moves(ary,a+1,b,sum_num,directions+="left ")
  end
  return arr_all_moves(ary,a,b+1,sum_num,directions+="right ") + 
         arr_all_moves(ary,a+1,b,sum_num,directions+="left ")
end

board = [   [1,3,4],
            [5,6,999],
            [8,9,10],
            [11,12,13],
            [2000,42,13]
        ]
p arr_all_moves(board)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution, and you should use `down` instead of `left` as we are traversing right or down the 2-D array to reach to lower right corner.

```
def arr_all_moves(ary, a=0, b=0, sum_num=0, directions=" ")
  rows = ary.length
  cols = ary[0].length

  sum_num += ary[a][b]

  if [a,b] == [rows-1,cols-1]
    [] << [sum_num, directions]
  elsif a == rows-1
    arr_all_moves(ary, a, b+1, sum_num, directions+="right ")
  elsif b == cols-1
    arr_all_moves(ary, a+1, b, sum_num, directions+="down ")
  else
    arr_all_moves(ary, a, b+1, sum_num, directions+="right ") + 
    arr_all_moves(ary, a+1, b, sum_num, directions+="down ")    
  end
end

board = [  
          [1,3,4],
          [5,6,999],
          [8,9,10],
          [11,12,13],
          [2000,42,13]
        ]

p arr_all_moves(board)
```